# $wpdb->get_results work but $result->meta_key shows nothing

Tags: wordpress

What I do wrong?

hey

I get nothing on
echo $result->meta_key;

but var_dump($result) shows result!

please advise

```
<?
php

global $wpdb;

$result = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT * FROM ' . $wpdb->postmeta . ' LIMIT 1');
//var_dump ($result);
echo $result->meta_key;

?>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate? It would be helpful if you included the output from `var_dump($result);`

Answer (score 0):

the `$result` is returned as an array. so you have to use first index to get data `$result[0]`

here is the code sample you need.

```
global $wpdb;
$result = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT * FROM ' . $wpdb->postmeta . ' LIMIT 1');
//var_dump ($result[0]);
echo $result[0]->meta_key;
```